# C# HttpWebRequest form upload

Tags: c#, forms, upload, httpwebrequest

im trying to automate a file upload from my C# program. This is the method to upload a file.

```
public static string UploadFileEx(string uploadfile, string url,
                            string fileFormName, string contenttype, NameValueCollection querystring,
                            CookieContainer cookies)
    {
        if ((fileFormName == null) ||
            (fileFormName.Length == 0))
        {
            fileFormName = "file";
        }

        if ((contenttype == null) ||
            (contenttype.Length == 0))
        {
            contenttype = "application/octet-stream";
        }


        string postdata;
        postdata = "";
        if (querystring != null)
        {
            foreach (string key in querystring.Keys)
            {
                postdata += key + "=" + querystring.Get(key) + "&";
            }
        }
        Uri uri = new Uri(url + postdata);

        string boundary = "----------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

        var sp = webrequest.ServicePoint;
        var prop = sp.GetType().GetProperty("HttpBehaviour", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        prop.SetValue(sp, (byte)0, null);

        webrequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
        webrequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        webrequest.Method = "POST";

        webrequest.KeepAlive = true;
        webrequest.Referer = "http://www.iwi.hs-karlsruhe.de/scs/simulate/upload.jsp";
        webrequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        webrequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.220 Safari/535.1";
        webrequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language:de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
        webrequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate");
        webrequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;


        // Build up the post message header

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("--");
        sb.Append(boundary);
        sb.Append("\r\n");
        sb.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"");
        sb.Append(fileFormName);
        sb.Append("\"; filename=\"");
        sb.Append(Path.GetFileName(uploadfile));
        sb.Append("\"");
        sb.Append("\r\n");
        sb.Append("Content-Type: ");
        sb.Append(contenttype);
        sb.Append("\r\n");
        sb.Append("\r\n");

        string postHeader = sb.ToString();
        byte[] postHeaderBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postHeader);

        // Build the trailing boundary string as a byte array

        // ensuring the boundary appears on a line by itself

        byte[] boundaryBytes =
               Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(uploadfile,
                                    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        long length = postHeaderBytes.Length + fileStream.Length +
                                               boundaryBytes.Length;
        webrequest.ContentLength = length;

        Stream requestStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream();

        // Write out our post header

        requestStream.Write(postHeaderBytes, 0, postHeaderBytes.Length);

        // Write out the file contents

        byte[] buffer = new Byte[checked((uint)Math.Min(4096,
                                 (int)fileStream.Length))];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

        // Write out the trailing boundary

        requestStream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length);
        try
        {
            WebResponse responce = webrequest.GetResponse();
            Stream s = responce.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);

            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

When i call it like this on a sample image upload page, everything works fine:

```
string outdata = UploadFileEx(uploadfile,
             "http://www.minpic.de/upload_file.php", "uploadfile0", "image/jpg",
             null, null);
```

But when i try to upload it to the page of my high school it's not working. The upload page is secured by a login form. So i call the upload page to get the initail Cookie, the i post the login credentials and get the right result. So i can see the following upload form:

```
<form action="../simulate" method=post enctype="multipart/form-data"><br />Choose your inputdata file (xml).<br /><input type=file size=50 maxlength=100000 name="Datei" accept="text/xml"><br><br><input type=submit value="Send"></form>
```

When i then post the image (i know the expected type is xml but the page answers a error what i want in this case ...) my upload function return a error code 500. Here is what wireshark says for the browsers post:

> POST /scs/simulate HTTP/1.1
>   Host: some host
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Content-Length: 3874
>   Cache-Control: max-age=0
>   Origin: same host
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4
>   Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryP3Ti6rxYcN1ov7JD
>   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Referer: some url
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
>   Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
>   Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
>   Cookie: SCS_COOKIE=Default=DE$$MarkePlaceLang=DE; JSESSIONID=B459541362241F66D9312AF157262D25

and here the post from c#:

> POST same as above
>   Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------8cf828671b8365c
>   Referer: some url
>   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.220 Safari/535.1
>   Accept-Language: de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   Host: same host as above
>   Cookie: JSESSIONID=FFE0B7530FFE6A3C8F15FD8A900865B0
>   Content-Length: 3847
>   Expect: 100-continue
>   Connection: Keep-Alive

The only difference i can see is the Expect: 100-continue ... Is there a problem with the packet size or something ?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you have to upload using multipart. This is shown in your browser post:

```
   Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryP3Ti6rxYcN1ov7JD
```

here is an example:
[Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data)

it makes sense because usually image size may be larger than the limit of usual post (2KB or 4KB, I forgot).

Comment: But i have "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" in both, browser and C# post.